# Real square matrix of order 7 has 6-dimensional invariant subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let A be real square matrix of order 7, then A has 6-dimensional invariant subspace.

How to prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equip ${\mathbb R}^n$ with the standard scalar product. The characteristic polynomial of the matrix $A'$ has degree $7$ and therefore a zero $\lambda\in{\mathbb R}$ by the IVT. Choose a nonzero vector $e$ with $A'e=\lambda e$, and let $U$ be the six-dimensional orthogonal complement of $\langle e\rangle$. I *claim* that $U$ is an invariant subspace of $A$.

*Proof.*  For $x\in U$ one has $Ax\cdot e=x\cdot A'e=\lambda\>x\cdot e=0$, which implies $Ax\in U$.

Answer (score 2):

First, since the characteristic polynomial has degree 7, there is at least one real eigenvalue. Going to the Jordan form we see that either we have one block or more. This determines the invariant spaces. If we have one block then we have only one dimensional invariant subspace.